# What is causing Save Query As dialog: The query will be saved on the following Team Foundation server

Tags: unit-testing

I was having some trouble seeing teammates' Code Review Requests in TFS and was poking around with stuff I don't know that much about.  All of a sudden, now, whenever I attempt to run a unit test in debug mode, I get a Save Query As popup with the referenced message.  I don't want this.  There are Save and Cancel options, and if I cancel, I am able to continue with the test.  Any clue what setting I hit (perhaps in My Work) that started this behavior?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the popup message?

Comment: I was getting the popup 100% of the time yesterday.  Having not consciously changed anything, except to put my computer to sleep overnight, I am not seeing it today, so unless it returns, I have to chalk it up to the environment.  I hate it when this happens :)